# Laravel json response retrieve via jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, laravel

How can I get particular data from Laravel json response. Please check the code below and help me to get each data separately

Code for json response.

```
$search_data = array();
    foreach ($searchCustomers as $searchCustomer)
    {
        $search_data[]= array(
            "firstnameletter" => ucfirst($searchCustomer->firstname),
            "lastnameletter"  => ucfirst($searchCustomer->lastname)
        );
    }
    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'search_data' => $search_data]);
```

How can I take each data separately eg firstnameletter?

```
{"success":true,"search_data":[{"firstnameletter":"","lastnameletter":"Test"},{"firstnameletter":"Thomas"
,"lastnameletter":"Tesar"},{"firstnameletter":"","lastnameletter":"Test"},{"firstnameletter":"Marcel"
,"lastnameletter":"Terlinden"},{"firstnameletter":"TEMMEL","lastnameletter":"WILFRIED"},{"firstnameletter"
:"Kfz","lastnameletter":"Technik"},{"firstnameletter":"","lastnameletter":"B\u00fcttel"},{"firstnameletter"
:"Autmobil","lastnameletter":"Technik"},{"firstnameletter":"","lastnameletter":"Test"},{"firstnameletter"
:"Flori","lastnameletter":"TEST"},{"firstnameletter":"","lastnameletter":"Test"},{"firstnameletter":"Kevin"
,"lastnameletter":"Tews"},{"firstnameletter":"G\u00fcnter","lastnameletter":"Braun"},{"firstnameletter"
:"Hasan","lastnameletter":"G\u00c3\u00b6kduman"},{"firstnameletter":"Test","lastnameletter":"Tester"
}]}
```

Below code is the js for getting response

JS

```
    $.post('searchbox', {searchData: searchField},
    function (html) {
      //alert(html.search_data[0]);
        for (var i = 0; i < html.length; i++) {
            alert(html[i]);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Use JSON.parse() https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another argument to tell jQuery that you received a JSON data

```
$.post('searchbox', 
    {searchData: searchField},
    function (json) {
        for (var i = 0; i < json.search_data.length; i++) {
            alert(json.search_data[i].firstnameletter);
        }
    },
    'json'
);
```

Another example on the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#example-6) page

Comment: Thank you so much I got it.